# The service is not available.The report server isn’t configured properly

Tags: sql, database, reporting-services, report

I can't connect to the report. I have recently installed sql reporting tools, but can't work with them. Have this problem
The service is not available.
The report server isn’t configured properly. Contact your system administrator to resolve the issue. System administrators: Check the report server trace log for details.